# Linux apropos command always returns "nothing appropriate"

Tags: linux, centos

I have a minimal installation of CentOS 5.7 32-bit on a VM.

The apropos command always returns "nothing appropriate"

```
[root@localhost ~]# apropos man
man: nothing appropriate
```

Even after I run updatedb. It works on another CentOS server I have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try executing 'makewhatis' as root. That updates the man page database, and creates it if it doesn't already exist, which it may not on a fresh installation.

'updatedb' updates the database for 'locate', and probably isn't related to this issue.

Comment: If using CentOS7 the command 'mandb' has replaced makewhatis.

Comment: I have run mandb as root. and it works.

Answer (score 8):

`sudo mandb` solved the problem for me.  It regenerates the apropos database, but you have to make sure you run it with sudo.

Comment: what and how, what did it do?

Comment: Apparently it regenerates the apropos database.   Answer modified.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo mandb -c` solved this issue for me on CentOS 8. The database needed to be created after a fresh install.

Comment: This answer has already been given twice.

Comment: "sudo mandb -c" is the correct one, thanks. Already given onces are slightly different :)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo mandb` worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04, no idea why this wasn't an issue on any of my other systems.

Slight annoyance is if you just run `mandb` without root privileges as some other answers forgot to mention, you just get unhelpful failure:

```
0 man subdirectories contained newer manual pages.
0 manual pages were added.
0 stray cats were added.
0 old database entries were purged.
```

Comment: Question is about CentOS